# C Shell "command not found" for standard tools using foreach path

Tags: csh

I am trying to use the awk in my C shell script to split my string.

When I use awk outside a loop, the command works. For instance:

```
set var = *
set path = `echo ${var[1]} | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}'`
```

However, when I use the same command inside a loop the following error appears **awk: command not found**.

For instance:

```
set var = *

foreach path ( $var )
    echo $path | awk '{split($0,a,"_"); print a[1]}'
end
```

Comment: Do not tag `bash` for questions about `csh` -- csh is from a completely different family; it's not even related to bash in the way that `sh` or `ksh` would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a variable name that's not `$path`, since this messes with Csh's program search path.